# Here is our students/Here are our students

Tags: grammar

Which is correct:

1. Here is our students.
2. Here are our students.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would be using "are", as in "here are our students". This is because you are using the verb  with more than one person. For example, "here is our student" when you are talking about only one student.